# Check if socket still open without blocking

Tags: sockets, tcp, common-lisp, nonblocking, sbcl

How do I check if a TCP socket is still open without blocking?

If I am using `usocket`, then reading from a socket stream will signal end of file if the socket is closed, but will block it otherwise, which I don't want. I have tried using `(listen stream)` to check in advance if the socket will be blocked, but `(listen)` returns `nil` on a closed socket, which does not help here. I have also tried checking `(usocket::state socket)`, which gives `:READ` on a closed socket, but it also sometimes gives `:READ` on an open socket even if there is not anything there. I am using sbcl, so I've tried using `(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-open-p)`, but that gives `T` on a closed socket, also not helpful. The only command that seems to be helpful is `(wait-for-input)`, namely it will return almost immediately when called on a closed socket, even when a longer timeout is given. At the same time, `(listen)` will still give `nil`, and that taken together seems to indicate a closed socket. This way looks rather hackish to me.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd use iolib : it has iolib:socket-connected-p and event handlers (epoll/select interface). It also comes with a good tutorial for sockets.

Comment: @coredump, thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specifically a Lisp problem. It's a problem inherent to TCP itself.

The only way in TCP to tell if a connection is still open is to try to send data over it, or to use TCP's keepalive feature (which sends data over the socket for you).

Linux, Windows, and MacOS all have the `SO_KEEPALIVE` socket option (see `setsockopt(2)`, which implements TCP keepalive. There are other associated sockopts, such as `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, and `TCP_KEEPCNT`, but they aren't portable between operating systems, and in Lisp you'll have the added challenge of finding the actual values of the C preprocessor constants, and of providing a pointer for the `option_value` argument.

I haven't had any luck using `SO_KEEPALIVE` on Linux, and I haven't tried using it on any other operating system.

Comment: I understand that the only way to check whether a connection has been dropped, is to send data over it. However, in my case the connection gets closed gracefully and the OS itself clearly knows about it. Otherwise, why would WAIT-FOR-INPUT start returning immediately? I've just checked with `lsof`, and it says CLOSE-WAIT instead of ESTABLISHED, so it's the CLOSE-WAIT state that I don't seem to be able to check using USOCKET.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in SBCL. The stream you get from `(usocket:socket-stream s)` and the one you get from calling `cl:open` are of the same type, so they behave the same way.

You get the correct behavior if you close a stream using `cl:close`:

```
(with-open-file (in "/dev/zero" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (close in)
  (listen in))
```

And that correct behavior is an error. (On SBCL the type of the error is `SB-INT:CLOSED-STREAM-ERROR`)

If you simulate the other end of a socket closing by closing the underlying file descriptor with a POSIX call, you get the same `NIL` return value as with a real socket:

```
(with-open-file (in "/dev/zero" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (sb-posix:close (slot-value in 'sb-impl::fd))
  (listen in)) ;; NIL
```

Whatever `listen` is doing is failing to notice that the underlying file descriptor is closed.

The blocking behavior is also identical:

```
(with-open-file (in "/dev/zero" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (sb-posix:close (slot-value in 'sb-impl::fd))
  (read-byte in)) ;; hangs, Emacs interrupt doesn't work
```

In the source code for `listen`, I saw comments that claim that select(2) is used to implement `listen`, but I couldn't find the actual call to `select`. That call to `select`, if it's happening, is returning `-1`, and `errno` is not being consulted to find out why. It's likely that the `-1` return code is being missed.

This affects the latest version of SBCL that Debian ships, but I don't know about the latest *released* version of SBCL.